# Online Example (CSS of a Cube) inside React

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to reproduce this cube inside of a webpage I am making using react (i am very new to react, so this question might be stupid)

https://codepen.io/jordizle/pen/haIdo/

So, I created a component, which contains the HTML structure for the cube.

```
class Cube extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="cube">
        <div id="wrapper">
  <div class="viewport">
    <div class="cube">
      <div class="side">
        <div class="cube-image">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="side">
        <div class="cube-image">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="side">
        <div class="cube-image">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="side">
        <div class="cube-image">4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="side">
        <div class="cube-image">5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="side">
        <div class="cube-image active">6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then, I simply added the CSS from the above website to a separate file, which I imported, like so:

```
import './ProductPage.css';
```

(see link above for css. The CSS is just copy pasted).

Finally, I created another component, which should render the cube, when it itself is rendered:

```
class NewProductPage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      img: null,
    };
    this.onDrop = this.onDrop.bind(this);
  }
  onDrop(acceptedFiles){
    this.setState({
      img: acceptedFiles[0].preview,
    })
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Cube />
        <div className="DropPicBox">
          <DropZone onDrop={this.onDrop}>
            {this.state.img ? 
              <div>
                <img className="PicBox" src={this.state.img} />
              </div> 
              : null}
          </DropZone>
        </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is rendered, but incorrectly:

[image]

My question is: is there something about the way react applies CSS that would change the way the cube looks? I used jfiddle to model this same cube using HTML and CSS from this website: https://codepen.io/jordizle/pen/haIdo/

And the cube looked correctly:

https://jsfiddle.net/jfj3muug/#&togetherjs=q2dv8HIMza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSX, to specify the class of an element, you have to use `className`, not `class`. E.g.:

```
<div className="foo">...</div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="foo">...</div>
```

You're doing that in *some* places, but `Cube` (your first codeblock) has `class` in several places.

Comment: You are magical - thank you. I will accept this answer in 7 minutes when git allows.